# Ubuntu 22.10 don't focus new "sub-windows"

Tags: gnome, window, 22.10

This is a weird one that I can't seem to find any solutions to. When I launch a sub-window, for example; when I press the "Open Folder" button in VS Code or just "Open in Terminal" in Nautilus, it starts but is not focused. It pops up behind the program that I launched it from. If that makes sense.

The new windows focus fine. When I do super+t for the terminal it gets focused as well when I launch from the overview or the dock. But not when launching from another program.

What I have tried:

- `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'strict'`
- `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'smart'`
- `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences auto-raise 'true'`
- Installed `dconf` and changed it right there.

Have I missed something obvious or is there any solution to this?